# Posso converter a saída de um objeto ao usar o get()?

Tags: python, tkinter, get, gui

Como posso converter a saída de um objeto ao usar a função get()? Visto que ela sempre retorna um valor
em string.
Aqui vai um código que estou escrevendo:

```
import tkinter as tk
import Sistema_backend

top = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(top, bg = "#159BA0", height = 500, width = 500)
canvas.pack()

Label1 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Digite sua nota:")
Label1.place(x = 10,y = 10)
Entry1 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry1.place(x = 100,y = 10)

Label2 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Digite sua nota:")
Label2.place(x = 10,y = 50)
Entry2 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry2.place(x = 100,y = 50)

Label3 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Digite sua nota:")
Label3.place(x = 10, y = 90)
Entry3 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry3.place(x = 100, y = 90)

Label4 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Digite sua nota:" )
Label4.place(x = 10, y = 130)
Entry4 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry4.place(x = 100, y = 130)

Label5 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Média mínima: ")
Label5.place(x=10, y = 170)
Entry5 = tk.Entry(canvas)
Entry5.place(x=100, y = 170)

Label5 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Total:")
Label5.place(x = 10,y = 210)
Label6 = tk.Label(canvas, text = "Resultado")
Label6.place(x = 10,y = 250) 

try:
    Button1 = tk.Button(canvas, text = "Enviar notas",
    command = Sistema_backend.Sistema(Entry1.get(float), 
    Entry2.get(float), Entry3.get(float), Entry4.get(float), Entry5.get(float)))
except:
    print('Algo de errado aconteceu!')
finally:
    Button1 = tk.Button(canvas, text = "Enviar notas")
    Button1.place(x = 10, y = 210)


Button2 = tk.Button(canvas, text = "Passou?")
Button2.place(x=10 , y= 290)

Label_result = tk.Label(canvas,text = "Resultado")
Label_result.place(x=10, y = 330)




canvas.mainloop()
```

Mais precisamente nesta parte:

```
try:
    Button1 = tk.Button(canvas, text = "Enviar notas",
    command = Sistema_backend.Sistema(Entry1.get(), 
    Entry2.get(), Entry3.get(), Entry4.get(), Entry5.get()))
except:
    print('Algo de errado aconteceu!')
finally:
    Button1 = tk.Button(canvas, text = "Enviar notas")
    Button1.place(x = 10, y = 210)
```

Basicamente, na GUI que eu importei, quando o user apertar o "Button1", ele vai enviar os dados. Estes
dados são obtidos a partir das "Entry" (tipo um input, Entry é só o nome que a biblioteca dá). A função
get() aí vai permitir que eu "extraia" os dados nos Entry, mas o problema é que ela retorna em STR, e
eu quero trabalhar com FLOAT, mas não sei como converter.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função `float()`. Vai ficar assim:

```
command = Sistema_backend.Sistema(float(Entry1.get()), 
    float(Entry2.get()), float(Entry3.get()), float(Entry4.get()), float(Entry5.get()))
```

Caso não seja inserido um valor numérico na Entry vai ser levantada uma exceção.
O número deve ser inserido usando ponto para separar a casa decimal. Se você usar vírgula vai dar erro também.

Comment: Cara, tentei isso que você falou mas não foi. Ele dá o erro antes mesmo de receber, então tentei colocar um lambda, e funcionou. Mas obrigado, mesmo assim.